# Django How to represent slug as ID for function based view

Tags: django, django-urls, slug

Im learning django and came across **slug** and Im struck while sending **arguments to function based view**

My urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Views.py

```
def detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=slug)
    comments=post.comment_set.all()
    forms=CommentForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.title = post
            print comment
            comment.save()
        else:
          print form.errors
    else:
        form = PostForm()
```

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def description_as_list(self):
        return self.description.split('\n')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug })
```

In the **second line** of views of views.py `post = Post.objects.get(id=slug)`,I feel this is **wrong representation**, What could be correct way of doing it?

I get following **error** for the above code
[image]

Any help is much appreciated..Thanks in advace

Comment: Can you show your `Post` model ?

Comment: @ParagTyagi-morpheus-..I have edited question by adding models.py...please check

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your post model has a slug field, you'll want to do:

```
post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

which can be translated as:

```
post = Post.objects.get(<name_of_field>=<argument_in_url>)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the `id` field in the `Post` model (which django creates itself) is an `AutoField` (check **[this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)**) which is basically a `bigint` field in terms of `sql`. Hence while querying on `id` field it expects a mandatory `int` value else will `raise` an `exception`.

In your case, the `Post` model should have a `slug` field, if it doesn't kind create one as below,

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    ...
    ...
```

And update your query as,

```
post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
```